# mysql left join with a VERY large table - super slow

Tags: mysql

[site_list] ~100,000 rows... 10mb in size.

- site_id
- site_url
- **site_data_most_recent_record_id**

[site_list_data] ~ 15+ million rows and growing... about 600mb in size.

- **record_id**
- site_id
- site_connect_time
- site_speed
- date_checked

---

columns in bold are **unique index keys.**

I need to return 50 most recently updated sites AND the recent data that goes with it - connect time, speed, date...
This is my query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  site_list.site_url,
  site_list_data.site_connect_time,
  site_list_data.site_speed,
  site_list_data.date_checked
FROM site_list
  LEFT JOIN site_list_data
    ON site_list.site_data_most_recent_record_id = site_list_data.record_id
ORDER BY site_data.date_checked DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Without the ORDER BY and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS(I need it for pagination), the query takes about 1.5 seconds, with those it takes over 2 seconds or more which is not good enough because that particular page where this data will be shown is getting 20K+ pageviews/day and this query is apparently too heavy(server almost dies when I put this live) and too slow.

Experts of mySQL, how would you do this? What if the table got to 100 million records? Caching this huge result into a temp table every 30 seconds is the only other solution I got.

Comment: You **really** need to cache the results of this query -- even for 1 min.  Setup a recurring task (cronjob) that runs the query every minute or 5 and push the data somewhere -- memcached, redis, a mysql table -- and then use it to show to the page visitors.

Comment: For other readers with a similar problem, this task is backwards. Whatever is inserting the related record should also be updating the parent record with its id so later lookups are done only on (preferably) unique keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a heuristic to the query. You need to gate the query to get reasonable performance. It is effectively sorting your site_list_date table by date descending -- the ENTIRE table.

So, if you know that the top 50 will be within the last day or week, add a "and date_checked > <boundary_date>" to the query. Then it should reduce the overall result set first, and THEN sort it.

Comment: bingo! 0.1 seconds after narrowing down my site_list_data results, changing left join to inner join and using count(*) instead of sql_calc_rows_found

Answer (score 1):

SQL_CALC_ROWS_FOUND is slow use COUNT instead. Take a look [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations.

Both `ORDER BY` and `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` are going to add to the cost of your performance.  `ORDER BY` clauses can potentially be improved with appropriate indexing -- do you have an index on your date_checked column?  This could help.

What is your exact need for `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`?  Consider replacing this with a separate query that uses `COUNT` instead.  This can be vastly better assuming your Query Cache is enabled.

And if you can use `COUNT`, consider replacing your `LEFT JOIN` with an `INNER JOIN` as this will help performance as well.

Good luck.